# Serializacion repetida en Winforms C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-forms

Necesito hacer esto https://youtu.be/GwAamiBq3uA y pude hacerlo, pero necesito crear algunos otros Textbox y también leer información de un archivo XML (pero no el mismo último archivo XML) He probado ese código pero eligiendo el XML con un Openfiledialog , pero sigue siendo el mismo último archivo XML

Comment: Hola @Seb, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Comment: Ya lo he completado, gracias por el comentario